# Remove default filtering by id in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to remove default filtering by `id` in django rest framework? I want to forbid(or filter by `_uid` field instead) requests like this `http://server/api/employee-list?employee=2`.

I wrote custom filter and add it to `filter_class` in my View:

```
class EmployeeFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = {
            'uid': ['exact', 'in'],
            'birth_date': ['day', 'month'],
            'first_name': NAME_FILTERS,
            'last_name': NAME_FILTERS,
            'middle_name': NAME_FILTERS,
        }
```

But is still able to filter by `id`.

Comment: is http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter this not useful?

Comment: What you mean by *default filtering by `id` in DRF* ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge i have no filter by `id`. I even don't show `id` in API, but if i make request `?employee=` it filtering by `id`.

Comment: can you show your models and views?